# App that identifies moves as Excellent/Good/Mistakes/Blunders

Tags: engines, analysis, android

I really like the analysis tool on chess.com that processes your games and identifies the Excellent and Good moves, as well as Mistakes and Blunders. It also proposes which move should have been played.

I realize it's probably based on a drop or increase in your piece advantage, but I really like this tool since I can clearly see what were my opponent's blunders or mistakes (as well as mine).

Is there an Android app that has similar features? The chess.com app allows me to analyse my chess.com games, but not to import a PNG and process it. Other analysis apps I've seen only return the "piece advantage score".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest starting at [lichess.org](http://lichess.org). It has tools that let you (1) analyze a game that you play on the site or (2) import a game and analyze it.

The lichess.org analysis includes inaccuracies, mistakes, and blunders. It does not have excellent or brilliancy (! or !!) markers, but they provide a rationale for why they don't use those. You can decide whether their explanation suffices for your purposes. They use a centipawns lost or gained graph that seems to be a good indicator of the game state. And they often suggest better moves with the corresponding alternate lines.

They have an Android app at https://en.lichess.org/mobile that you can try out to see if it meets your needs. You can also try out their web site on a mobile device to see how that works, too.

Finally, what I like about lichess.org is that they seem to have a great interest in having a clean, stylish piece and game user interface and they also seem to be actively developing, so if you have suggestions they may take a listen.

EDIT: Somehow I neglected to mention earlier that the site is free and the code is open source. Both are great if you want to save some money while learning chess and even possibly get interested in seeing how the site code works.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

[PGN ChessBook](https://pgnchessbook.org/)

Which is a free app that can be installed from SourceForge or from the Windows app store.

It finds blunders, then automatically annotates games by inserting variations and adding comments to the blunder moves, as described on

[Automatic game annotation features](https://pgnchessbook.org/gamesfindblunders/)

And in this YouTube video

[How to annotate games automatically using PGN ChessBook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJpre9WO9Sk)

Of course [ChessBase](https://shop.chessbase.com/en/cat_root) and several other paid apps can also do this, but they can be expensive.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to lichess, which has a great service for analyzing, Analyze This (Free) is a good app which lets you auto-analyze games, and has a beta feature which will identify blunders, mistakes, annotate your games for you, and suggest other lines.

Comment: I've been using Analyze This for a while and never noticed this function! Do you know if it's been added recently?

Comment: I believe within the past year.

Answer (score 2):

I'd point out that lichess.org uses the Stockfish engine which is regularly one of the top 3 most powerful chess analysis engines available (and its free):
[CCRL Chess Engine ratings through competitive competitions](http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/404/)

Although I completely agree with the recommendation to check to checkout lichess.org why not its engine directly in Android?  Download 'Droidfish' for Android:
[Droidfish Download](https://stockfishchess.org/download/)

Comment: Also, if you don't like the Stockfish engine, you can download one of its competitors such as Komodo chess engine or Fire5.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I have set up a free app exactly for this occasion, the chess blunder trainer: You import your own past games, and the tool will identify weak moves and generate puzzles from the positions. You can then replay the positions and like this improve your chess skills :)

Try it out in the Google Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cbt.chess_blunder_trainer

[image: Chess Blunder Trainer App]

You can find out more about the app here as well: [www.chessblundertrainer.com](https://www.chessblundertrainer.com)